# Get content of textarea in time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following code always omit the last written character.

```
$('#input').keypress(function(event){
    var content = $(this).val();
    console.log(content);
});
```

input `a`-> output `<nothing>`

input `ab` -> output `a`

input `abc` -> output `ab`

etc.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/huzpne7u/)

I want to get the **actual** written characters in the `textarea` each time.

Comment: 1) add jQuery to the fiddle 2) use the `keyup` event: https://jsfiddle.net/huzpne7u/1/

Comment: `keypress` and `keydown` fires when the key is pressed down, before the character is outputted, `keyup` fires after the key is released etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keypress` fires "too soon" for what you want -- you are always retrieving the **previous** character (thus never seeing the last character).  One option, among several, is to use the `keyup` event.